# Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $a^2 + b^2$ is a prime number. Prove that...

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

When you observe carefully, the question does not have much factorization that you can do.
Do you have any rearrangements in mind?

Let a and b be positive integers such that $a^2 + b^2$ is a prime number. Prove that the
equation $x^2 + ax + b + 1 = 0$ does not have integer roots.

Playing with the discriminant also does not seem to work.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the rational root theorem?  I am not sure it helps.

Comment: Hint: let $p,q$ be the roots, then $p+q=-a$ and $pq = b+1$ by Vieta's formulas, so $a^2+b^2 = \dots$

Comment: @dxiv Got it...

Comment: @RossMillikan Could you elaborate? I have tried what dxiv has suggested.

Comment: $a^2+b^2$ will give $(p^2+1)(q^2+1)$ which will be a prime number then what

Comment: @dxiv please elaborate

Comment: @LalitTolani $a^2 + b^2$ is composite. Thus, we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: @LalitTolani How many ways can you write a prime number as a product of positive integers? All that's left is to exclude the case where $p=0$ or $q=0$.

Comment: @dxiv I understood that if roots are integers either of $p^2+1$ and $q^2+1$ have to be equal to 1 giving either $p=0$ or $q=0$ and hence in either case $b=-1$ but $b$ needs to be positive which gives a contradiction but I didn't understand your second last comment , how $a^2+b^2$ will be a composite

Comment: @LalitTolani You wrote in a comment that $a^2+b^2=(p^2+1)(q^2+1)$, which is correct. So if $p,q$ are integers and neither can be $0$, then you have a prime written as a product of two integers strictly greater than $1$, which is not possible.

Comment: Yes clear now @dxiv thankyou

Comment: @mathx You may consider posting a self-answer to questions that you solved yourself. This would remove the question from MSE's "unanswered" list, and would help future readers of these questions. It can also be useful for you to doublecheck the proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
Try to prove $a^2 + b^2$ can be written as the product of two factors.